# How to access folders in a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, save, directory, runnable

My program has a folder called data - which stores text files- when i click save in my JAR application though nothing happens. How can i make it so i can access and save new files? Here is some of the code

```
public void saveAs() {
     FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
     fileChooser.setTitle("Save Routine"); fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("data/routines"));
     fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("txt", "*.txt"));
     if (fileName != null) {
         fileChooser.setInitialFileName(fileName);
     }
     save(fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage));
}
```

I also did it with a absolute path and that did not work either

Comment: You cannot save files in a jar, if that's what you mean. Well, everything is possible, but resource files in a jar are basically for reading, not for writing.

Comment: Is there an alternative to jars? or is there another way i can save it outside the jar?

Comment: it also wont let me read files either

Comment: You could do one of three things: either ask the user for a directory to save, use a platform-dependent AppData-type folder, or you could take a look at the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html), explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html).

Comment: For reading, you are supposed to use the class loader's `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` methods, not file access methods.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your save(java.io.File) method, I can't say. [FileChooser.showSaveDialog](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showSaveDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) just shows the dialog and tells you what file they chose (if any). You then have to write it whether it's a JAR or txt.

Try this:

```
private void save(File where){
  if(where==null){ //they canceled.
    return;
  }
  try(OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(where.toPath())){
    //Write to out.
  }
}
```

You can write things into JAR files with the plain [JarFile constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#JarFile-java.io.File-), but it looks like you want plain text files. Although you may be able to update your application's JAR files while it's running, most programs don't do that because it's odd.